# Creation of multiple instance of an object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently learning laravel and stuck with an assignment. I have the program where User will have multiple Whiteboards where he can post his notes. What i want to achieve is when User is created it should create 4 different Whiteboards.

This is working for 1 Whiteboard creation but not sure how I can achieve 4 while creating user. I have relationship set up where each user can have multiple Whiteboards and each Whiteboard will have only one User.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $whiteboard = Whiteboard::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'name'     => $data['name'],
    ]);
    return User::create([
        'email'       => $data['email'],
        'password'    => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'whiteboard_id' => $whiteboard->id,
    ]);
}
```

I expect something like this (Just dummy example) -

User A should have whiteboards created with ID 1,2,3,4 
User B should have whiteboards created with ID 5,6,7,8

Comment: How do you want to store the 'whiteboard_id' for user A in database? something like "1-2-3-4" (seperated by '-') ?

Comment: The user model should have many whiteboards and one whiteboard has only one user?
Then you should have user_id field on the whiteboard models table. Read up on the eloquent relationships documentation.

Comment: @NabilFarhan I am keeping single table columns for whiteboards, they are in one single db columns. 1 to 4 are seperate IDs

Comment: @NikoPeltoniemi Yes that is set up. Thanks for heads up, added this info in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do somethings like this,

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'email'       => $data['email'],
        'password'    => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    for($i=0; $i<=3; $i++)
    {
      $whiteboard = Whiteboard::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'name'     => $data['name'],
        'user_id'  => $user->id
      ]);
    }
    return $user;

}
```

In that case you have to change your relationship User (one) Whiteboard (many)

Comment: Still creates one instance only. Also your code is missing $ in for loop